# ggparcoord axes adjustments: remove default labels, remove extra spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'd like to remove the default "variable" and "value" labels on the axes of ggparcoord plots:

```
library(GGally)
ggparcoord(data = mtcars,
           columns = c(4:5),
           groupColumn = 1,
           scale = "globalminmax",
           alphaLines = 0.2)
```

[image: example ggparcoord plot]

I'd also like to remove the default extra spaces on either end of the x-axis. How can I make these custom axis adjustments? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `axis.title.x` (or `.y`) for changing the titles and `expand` to remove the extra white-space beyond the limits.

```
ggparcoord(data = mtcars,
           columns = c(4:5),
           groupColumn = 1,
           scale = "globalminmax",
           alphaLines = 0.2) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.1,0.1))
```

I used `c(0.1,0.1)` to have some space beyond the limits as it would look cleaner but you can use `c(0,0)` for `expand` to remove all the spaces beyond the x limits.

[image]